# Arduino SoftSerial won't receive whole text when using delay

Tags: arduino

I have this strange problem with my code below. If I remove the "delay" line, code works fine. If I leave it there, and then send a text through SoftSerial, that text won't get received as a whole but the received text will be a few characters short. The same happens if I use `millis` for the delay. Are SoftSerial and delay that incompatible? Is there a workaround?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define DEBUG            true
#define relayPin1           8    //Output for relay pin 1
#define relayPin2           7    //Output for relay pin 2
#define relay1Run           5    //Load relay 1 feedback pin 
#define relay2Run           6    //Load relay 2 feedback pin 
#define NOP __asm__ __volatile__ ("nop\n\t")

SoftwareSerial SIM900(10, 11); // RX, TX

char phoneNumber[16]={'\0'};
char simExpirationDate[11]={'\0'};  //31/12/2017
char smsExpirationDate[11]={'\0'};  //31/12/2017
char signalStrength[8]={'\0'};      //100/100
char cardRemainingBalance[7]={'\0'};
char cardExpirationDate[11]={'\0'};  //31-12-2017
char autoReportsOnOff[5]={' ', 'O', 'F', 'F', '\0'};        //AUTO
char outputPinToRelay1[4]={'O', 'F', 'F', '\0'};            //OFF
char outputPinToRelay2[4]={'O', 'F', 'F', '\0'};            //OFF
char relay1State[4]={'O', 'F', 'F', '\0'};                  //OFF
char relay2State[4]={'O', 'F', 'F', '\0'};                  //OFF
byte reportsOnOffSetting = 2;  //0=off, 1=on, 2=auto
int timeout=2000L;
byte tempValue=0;

void setup() {
  // if(DEBUG)Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SIM900.begin(9600);
  pinMode(relayPin1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relayPin1, HIGH);
  pinMode(relayPin2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relayPin2, HIGH);
  pinMode(relay1Run, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(relay1Run, HIGH);
  pinMode(relay2Run, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(relay2Run, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  char *textReceived;
  textReceived = (char *) malloc(90);
  if(SIM900.available()) {
    delay(1000);
    readData(timeout, 89, textReceived);
    Serial.print("textReceived: ");
    Serial.println(textReceived);
    free(textReceived);
    delay(40000L);
  }
}

byte readData(long int timeout,int charsToRead, char *textRecieved) {
  unsigned long time = millis();
  byte counter=0;
  while((time+3000L) > millis()) {
    while(SIM900.available()) {
      if(counter>=charsToRead)SIM900.read();
      else {
        textReceived[counter] = SIM900.read();
        if((textReceived[counter]) == '\0')goto here;
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }
  textReceived[counter] = '\0';
  return counter;
  here:
    return counter;
}

void sendData(char *data) {
  SIM900.print(data); // send the read character to the ESP8266
  if(DEBUG) Serial.println(data);
 }
```

Comment: 1) end of loop is start of next loop: why do you malloc/free ? 2) you probably wont receive a `'\0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, I would'nt write code like this. But to fix your problem you should make at tiny delay in the `while(SIM900.available())` loop.
The problem is that the loop runs faster than the serial data is coming in, so the `SIM900.available()` statement will be false even though there are more data coming. A `delay(1);` will properly do.

Like this.

```
while(SIM900.available()) {
  if(counter>=charsToRead)SIM900.read();
  else {
    textReceived[counter] = SIM900.read();
    if((textReceived[counter]) == '\0')goto here;
    counter++;
  }
  delay(1);  // Add this.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer is probably being overrun. Also, there are 2 delays in your code. Maybe you could say which line you are talking about.

Finally, you are using a pooling method to read your UART. You should try to use an interrupt when possible. You can find some good info here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent